# Scraping using rvest-can't identify html nodes

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to set up a web scraper to pull data from the website referenced in the url below. I'm using the `rvest` package in r and am [following the instructions here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/).

So far I have the following code to pull the first Data point but am getting a `character(0)` response when executing `statustext` error message. Any suggestions?

```
url <- 'https://www.ttbonline.gov/colasonline/viewColaDetails.do?action=publicDisplaySearchAdvanced&ttbid=10328001000040'
#This url will be modified to scrape multiple unique urls. 

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrape the status section
status <- html_nodes(webpage,'.box tr:nth-of-type(3) td[valign]')

#Converting the status data to text
statustext <- html_text(status)

statustext
```

Modification showing screen shot.
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using rvest 0.3.4, R 3.6.1, Windows 10. Your code generates `statustext` with the expected value "\n                    Status: \n                     \n                    APPROVED\n                  ".

Comment: Strange, I'm using a Mac Mojave 10.14.4 system and rvest 0.3.4

Comment: I'm using Mac Mojave 10.14.6 rvest 0.3.4 and R 3.6.1 and I too can't reproduce the issue and get the same value as @neilfws .

Comment: I'm using RStudio. I've just added a screenshot showing exactly what I see.

Comment: I'm using RStudio cannot reproduce